# Photoshop cs6 hiding text behind background color

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am new to photoshop design. I am trying to design a website template using photoshop. I have my header part with background color. After that i created new layer called `Home` meny it is not visible. Header is hiding my text and whatever i draw i cant see. can anyone guess where I am wrong.

Comment: Hi Relic! Can you please add a screenshot of your problem? Otherwise it's mostly guessing for us!

Comment: I need 10 reputation to add screenshot

Comment: You can post a link to a picture (and someone with more rep can can add it for you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the layer you are drawing/typing on is below your background, so it's being covered.

You can change the order of the layers by dragging them up or down in the list. If you don't have the layers panel open, you can do so with either F7 (Windows) or using the Window -> Layers menu option.

You can also temporarily hide or display any layer by clicking the eye icon next to that layer in the panel.